# Symfony2 Forms - custom input names

Tags: php, symfony

I use Symfony2 form generation in a common way.

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ValueType(), $entity);
$view = $form->createView();
```

This renders form like

```
<input name="test_commonbundle_valuetype[value]" ...
```

How to make it to **generate custom names** - like

```
<input name="test_commonbundle_sometype[values][N][value]"
```

**?**

*I need it as i manually render entity template for parent object w/ajax processing - so getting child object and form.values does not suit for me.*

Answer (score 1):

In your form type you can add the property_path => false option to add a field to the form without being used by the entity.

```
$builder->add('myFancyName','text',array('property_path' => false);
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `[`, `]` symbols: `The name "ticket[filters][0]" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").`